# EC2でembulkを実行しても、通信出来ない旨のエラー文が出て実行時できません。

Tags: java, embulk

EC2でembulkを実行しても、通信出来ない旨のエラー文が出て実行時できません。

やりたいことはEC2内のローカルmysql DB dev2からdev3へDB内容をreplaceする処理になります。
なので以下のようなconfigファイルを書いて実行しています。

```
in:
  type: mysql
  host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  user: root
  password: "xxxxx"
  database: dev2
  socket_timeout: 0
  # 18.183.204.253

out:
  type: mysql
  host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  user: root
  password: "xxxxx"
  database: dev3
  mode: replace
```

そして出ているエラーが以下になります。
なにかアイデアをいただけましたらありがたいです。

```
org.embulk.exec.PartialExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$LoaderState.buildPartialExecuteException(BulkLoader.java:340)
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.doRun(BulkLoader.java:566)
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.access$000(BulkLoader.java:35)
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$1.run(BulkLoader.java:353)
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$1.run(BulkLoader.java:350)
        at org.embulk.spi.Exec.doWith(Exec.java:23)
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.run(BulkLoader.java:350)
        at org.embulk.EmbulkEmbed.run(EmbulkEmbed.java:242)
        at org.embulk.EmbulkRunner.runInternal(EmbulkRunner.java:291)
        at org.embulk.EmbulkRunner.run(EmbulkRunner.java:155)
        at org.embulk.cli.EmbulkRun.runSubcommand(EmbulkRun.java:431)
        at org.embulk.cli.EmbulkRun.run(EmbulkRun.java:90)
        at org.embulk.cli.Main.main(Main.java:64)
        Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.doCleanup(BulkLoader.java:463)
                at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$3.run(BulkLoader.java:397)
                at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$3.run(BulkLoader.java:394)
                at org.embulk.spi.Exec.doWith(Exec.java:23)
                at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.cleanup(BulkLoader.java:394)
                at org.embulk.EmbulkEmbed.run(EmbulkEmbed.java:245)
                ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at org.embulk.input.jdbc.AbstractJdbcInputPlugin.transaction(AbstractJdbcInputPlugin.java:227)
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.doRun(BulkLoader.java:507)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:341)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2189)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2222)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2017)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:779)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
        at org.embulk.input.mysql.MySQLInputPlugin.newConnection(MySQLInputPlugin.java:130)
        at org.embulk.input.mysql.MySQLInputPlugin.newConnection(MySQLInputPlugin.java:27)
        at org.embulk.input.jdbc.AbstractJdbcInputPlugin.transaction(AbstractJdbcInputPlugin.java:213)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
        ... 29 more

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

アクセスキーとシークレットキーを入力してないから動かないのではないですか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。